# SQL Server Management Studio raises error when running a script

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I try to seed database with data via script

I run it via SSMS

But when I start to execute it, I have this error

[image]

[image]

Here is Memory properties

[image]

How I can fix it?

Here is last data in Log

```
>  <entry>
    <record>177</record>
    <time>2017/09/08 08:42:14.686</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type &apos;System.OutOfMemoryException&apos; was thrown.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.String.CtorCharArray(Char[] value)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Implementation.BinaryStringRebuilder.GetText(Span span)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Implementation.TextSnapshot.GetText(Span span)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.SnapshotSpan.GetText()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.TextDocData.GetLineText(Int32 iStartLine, Int32 iStartIndex, Int32 iEndLine, Int32 iEndIndex, String&amp; pbstrBuf)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.Source.GetText()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.Source.BeginParse(Int32 line, Int32 idx, TokenInfo info, ParseReason reason, IVsTextView view, ParseResultHandler callback)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.ViewFilter.GetDataTipText(TextSpan[] aspan, String&amp; textValue)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.TryGetQuickInfoFromFilter(IQuickInfoSession session, TextSpan[] dataBufferTextSpan, String&amp; tipText)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.AugmentQuickInfoSession(IQuickInfoSession session, IList`1 qiContent, ITrackingSpan&amp; applicableToSpan)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Recalculate()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Start()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.DefaultQuickInfoController.OnTextView_MouseHover(Object sender, MouseHoverEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.RaiseHoverEvents()</description>
  </entry>
```

Comment: What did the log say? And what was your script?

Comment: You get an error from **SSMS**. Not SQL Server. Modifying an unrelated application's memory settings will only *create* problems. Explain what you actually did. You were able to open the `Server Properties` after all

Comment: maybe the script would be helpful

Comment: `I try to seed database with data via script` does your script output data to ssm grid

Comment: Did you examine the xml file? What does it say?

Comment: Updated post @HoneyBadger

Comment: see this :https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75326/management-studio-system-outofmemoryexception

Comment: Another dev send me data that fill tables with data. I try To execute it, but I get error about memory. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: How do you expect any help if you don't show that script? What does that script do? How big is it?

Comment: The error's exception stack shows that it was raised while trying to draw text. This could happen if eg someone sent a script dump of a database instead of a backup. Not smart. Use the `sqlcmd` command-line tool to execute the script instead of SSMS.